# How to add a CSS class depending on URL path?

Tags: javascript, css, class

How can I add an CSS class to an div depending on what path I am on, including that it should not mather if I had # in it?

```
<div class="popup">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#vs">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bod">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ptf">Example 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- popup -->

<!-- how would I add the class addMe with javascript depending on the site path? It has to work with # -->
```

[jsfiddle.net/zatox50/wBxkj/](http://jsfiddle.net/zatox50/wBxkj/)

Example index.html

Comment: give some examples of URLs and tell your criteria to get the class name.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `$($(this).attr('href')).addClass('addMe');` (_using jquery_).

Comment: Maybe this is usefull http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-jquery-to-highlight-active-menu-item ??

Comment: @Mr_Green It looks like what I need, could you fork my fiddle and show it in use there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($){
   switch(window.location.hash){
      case "vs":  $(".popup").addClass("class1"); break;
      case "bod":  $(".popup").addClass("class2"); break;
      case "ptf":  $(".popup").addClass("class3"); break;
   }
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, what should stand in after the "case" if I dont use an anker? Example if I use /index.html.

Comment: then use `switch(window.location.href)`

Comment: I can't get it to work, I use this. `jQuery(function($){
      switch(window.location.href){
      case "index.html":  $(".popup.").addClass("addMe"); break;
      }
   });`

Answer (score 0):

none of these worked for me. this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        // Get current url
        // Select an a element that has the matching href and apply a class of 'active'.     Also prepend a - to the content of the link
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.menu a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

menu structure:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-element">001</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-element">002</a>
</div>
```

source: http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-jquery-to-highlight-active-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

## This is the simple code for create Dynamic active menu for website by using JavaScript & JQuery.

```
<style>
.myactive{
     background-color:#F7A751;
    }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var url = window.location.pathname; 
var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    activePage === '' ?  $('#home').addClass("myactive") : $('#home').removeClass("myactive") ; // for active index page
    activePage === 'about-us' ? $('#about').addClass("myactive") : $('#about').removeClass("myactive") ; //active about us 
    activePage === 'who-we-are' ? $('#info').addClass("myactive") : 
    $('#info').removeClass("myactive") ; 
});
</script>  

#HTML Part....
 <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
```